# Grails Webflow: Access flow scope outside of action or transition states

Tags: grails, spring-webflow

I want to call a subflow where the controller is not known. It is passed in parameters to beginFlow and I save that in flow scope. Inside goToForm I'd like to call use the controller that is saved in flow.theController.

---

```
def beginFlow = {
    enter {
        action {
            if (params?.redirectTo != null) {
                String flow.theController = params.redirectTo
            }

            if ( flow.theController() ) { 
                success()
            }
        }
        on("success").to("beginPage")
    }
    beginPage {
        on('next').to('goToForm')
    }       
    goToForm {
                    // I'd like this:
                    // subflow(controller: flow.theController, action:'start'

                    // this subflow works, but won't work for all cases
        subflow(controller: 'AZ_A4', action:'start')
        on('done').to('showResults')
        on('notDone').to('beginPage')
    }

    showResults {
        redirect(action: 'results')
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As discussed on the user list, it appears that this isn't possible directly, as the subflow name has to be known at the time when the flow structure is being built (at application startup).  But since the flow definition DSL is Groovy code you can do something like this:

```
beginPage {
    on('next').to('selectSubflow')
}
selectSubflow {
    action {
        return "subflow_${flow.theController}"()
    }
    for(subController in listOfControllers) {
        on("subflow_${subController}").to("subflow_${subController}")
    }
}
for(subController in listOfControllers) {
    "subflow_${subController}" {
        subflow(controller:subController, action:'start')
        on('done').to('showResults')
        on('notDone').to('beginPage')
    }
}
```

The listOfControllers could be a static somewhere, or you could possibly do something like this at the top of the flow definition

```
def beginFlow = {
    def listOfControllers = grailsApplication.controllerClasses.findAll {
        it.flows.containsKey('start')
    }.collect { it.logicalPropertyName }
    enter {
        // ...
```

to enumerate all the controllers in the application that define a startFlow.  You might need a `def grailsApplication` in your class, I always forget which places in Grails have it available by default and which don't...