# Grails webflow dynamic step name

Tags: grails, spring-webflow

I started using Grails web flow in order to implement a wizard.

```
checkStep {

        action {
            User user = springSecurityService.currentUser
            if (springSecurityService.loggedIn){
                def next = wizardService.getNextFlowStep(user)
                switch (next) {
                       case step1: 
                              step1()
                              break
    ...
                 }
         }
         on("step1").to "wizard_step1"
  } // checkStep
 wizard_step1() {
  ...
 }
```

I'd like to write the first step in more elegant way, such that based on "wizardService" the next step will be determined. I also preferred that the steps will be determined at run time, such that the actual step names and order may be reside in a database.

THanks

Answer (score 0):

You want to use groovy's [dynamic method invocation](http://groovy.codehaus.org/Dynamic+Groovy) for something like this.  I'm not sure if this will actually work inside of a webflow but it should look something like this....

```
        def next = wizardService.getNextFlowStep(user); // returns 'step1';
        "${next}"(); // you may have to use 'this."${next}"();'
```

Comment: With this solution you will still need to explicitly enumerate all the `on('foo').to('bar')` options (though this could be done with a for loop if the event and state names follow some structure).  I don't think there's a way around this, the structure of the flow (states and transitions) needs to be known at the point when the application starts up.  [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11126683/grails-webflow-access-flow-scope-outside-of-action-or-transition-states/11168991#11168991) talks about a similar situation involving subflows.