# Webflow - Several transitions doing the same action

Tags: grails, spring-webflow

In my user interface I have several tabs, where every tab is a state in a grails webflow.

From TAB1 it is possible to go to TAB2, TAB3, TAB4

From TAB2 it is possible to go to TAB1, TAB3, TAB4
...

For EVERY transition in EVERY state I currently execute the same code for validation and define transitions like:

```
on("TAB2") {
    log.debug("Navigating to zu TAB2")
    bindData(flow.carInstance, params)
    if (!flow.carInstance.validate()) {
        return error()
    }
}.to "TAB2"

on("TAB3") {
    log.debug("Navigating to zu TAB3")
    bindData(flow.carInstance, params)
    if (!flow.carInstance.validate()) {
        return error()
    }
}.to "TAB3"
....
```

Refering to [Grails Webflow: Access flow scope outside of action or transition states](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11126683/grails-webflow-access-flow-scope-outside-of-action-or-transition-states) I created a for loop to create the tranistions dynamically. The navigation seems to work but the logs show "Navigating to TAB4" (the last entry in the collection) on EVERY transition.

```
for (step in ["TAB2", "TAB3", "TAB4"]) {
      on(step) {
         log.debug("Navigating to ${step}")
         bindData(flow.carInstance, params)
         if (!flow.carInstance.validate()) {
             return error()
         }
    }.to step
}
```

Why? Is it ok to implement it like this? Grails doesn't define global transitions, I think...

Comment: afaik it is possible to use wildcards in transitions and veiwstates. http://grails.1312388.n4.nabble.com/grails-and-webflow-viewstate-transitions-and-wildcards-td1378806.html

Comment: I tried but wildcards don't work. Because all transitions have to be known at compile time. But anyway, wildcards wouldn't be a solutions for me, as I already know all possible transitions at compile time. I only don't want to duplicate code.